# Can `writing-mode: horizontal-tb;` be used per character?

Tags: css, cjk, chinese-locale

The caron `ˇ` character in the screenshot is rotated due to it not being recognized as Chinese character, just like the word `Prologue` in the screenshot is rotated too

`ˇ` is rotated, hence it looks like `<` character

Can `writing-mode: horizontal-tb;` be applied on per character basis?

I just want it to be applied on tones 1 to 4:

```
export const ACTUAL_TONES = {
    1: '¯',
    2: '´',
    3: 'ˇ',
    4: '`',
    // https://emptycharacter.com/
    5: '\u00A0',
};
```

If `writing-mode: horizontal-tb;` cannot be applied on per character basis, are there any equivalent Chinese unicodes for the above accent/tone marks? So they will not be rotated by the browser

[image]

To repro the problem, install this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-words-separator/gacfacdpfimbkgcnlegknnmcccjgcbnp

And then load this site (need Google login): https://new-read.readmoo.com/mooreader/210225690000101/preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use `text-orientation: upright`

[image]